# How to make gradients in Chrome smooth?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, linear-gradients

This is how it looks in Chrome :

[image]

and this is a screenshot from Firefox :

[image]

It is clear from the screenshots that the gradient boundaries are jagged in Chrome. How can I make them smooth?

Here is my gradient in case that matters:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, red 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, red 75%, red),
                  linear-gradient(-45deg, red 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, red 75%, red);
background-size: 60px 60px;
background-position:0 0, 30px 30px;
```

**EDIT:**

Changing the background-size to 40px makes the gradient smooth but I want it to be smooth at all sizes.

Let me know if I need to provide additional code. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe provide us with your HTML and how you are overlaying the triangles over the gradient so we can see how its structured?

Comment: I don't think the HTML matters here because just setting the property on `body` will produce the output. @SanJeetSingh: By the way, what is the `background-size` that you are using? I tried it with `40px 40px` in Chrome and it produces same output as Firefox.

Comment: @Harry Yup, the gradient was smooth with 40px. I am using 60 px though. Ideally, I would like the gradient to be smooth at all dimensions.

Comment: @SanJeetSingh: Interesting. I am using a older version of Chrome (v43) and with the new settings that you've provided the whole output looks weird and different. Maybe something has regressed or changed between the versions.

Comment: @Harry The gradient is smooth at some sizes and jagged at others. I am using chrome version 48.

Comment: @SanJeetSingh that's a known problem. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35898219/5035890

Comment: @SanJeetSingh: Does [this](https://jsfiddle.net/y7jtp6qp/) solve your problem? It is only a workaround but in my version of Chrome it works. Let me know if it helps and I will post it as answer.

Comment: @Harry Yes it worked. How did you guess it? Do I need to keep experimenting with percentage values or will it work with all sizes? Why did it work?

Comment: No not much experimentation is needed @SanJeetSingh. When one colour ends at 25% and next starts at same position, it is called a hard stop gradient (that is, color changes immediately) and such gradients when made at a angle are known to cause trouble. Giving a gap between one color and another smoothed the change and hence reduces the jagged edges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Reason:**

As I had described in comments, when the end point of one color is the start point of another (that is, a hard-stop gradient), the change of colors is sudden and such a sudden change at an angle is known for producing rough edges even in other browsers (which has maybe got fixed by now). Giving a gap between end point of one color and start of the next produces a smoother change of color and thus minimises rough edges.

Not much experimentation is required for this (or trial and error), a 1 or 2% gap is almost always sufficient.

**Workaround:**

Changing the color stop points to produce a more smooth change of colors instead of giving it a hard stop seems to be helping.

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, red 24%, transparent 26%, transparent 74%, red 76%, red), linear-gradient(-45deg, red 24%, transparent 26%, transparent 74%, red 76%, red);
  background-size: 60px 60px;
  background-position: 0 0, 30px 30px;
}
```

Comment: Good @Harry! There's a lot of reasons because this kind of things are produced. Another brain note. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah @MarcosPérezGude. I remember coming across the `backface-visibility` option earlier too but for some reason that wasn't working for this one. So yeah, one problem and different possible workarounds which work only for some cases :(

Answer (score 3):

It is produced by a bug in chrome, that treats that kind of backgrounds as a 3D element. You can avoid that writing a border (it converts to flat the element), or with this property.

```
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

OR

```
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Webkit specifically! */
```

The border solution

```
  border: 1px solid #fff;
```

See more about this bug:

http://adrianroselli.com/2014/10/linear-gradient-problems-in-chrome.html

Comment: Are you sure? Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net or a stacksnippet to show the problem?

Comment: Please wait while I create the fiddle :).

Comment: I wait exactly 5 minutes, because it's time to leave the office here in Spain :), but I be stay in tune.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `backface-visibility: hidden`

This happens sometimes when we ask a browser to skew an image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on the elements the gradient is in.

```
transform: translateZ(0);
```

It smoothens the gradient. See below.

```css
td.normal {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, red 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, red 75%, red),
  linear-gradient(to top right, red 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, red 75%, red);
}

td.smooth {
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td class="normal"></td>  
  <td class="normal"></td>
  <td class="normal smooth"></td>
  <td class="normal smooth"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```